# docker compose exec changing my parameter value

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    server:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
```

so my service name is `server`. When i try to do this:

```
docker-compose exec server sh
```

it gives me an error:

> ERROR: No container found for server_1

why is it changing my param from `server` to `server_1`? and what's the correct way to run this command? I tried this too:

```
docker-compose ps

// output: name: website-service-api_server_run_dfb252d8a1fc
// then

docker-compose exec website-service-api_server_run_dfb252d8a1fc sh
```

same error:

> ERROR: No such service: website-service-api_server_run_dfb252d8a1fc

Comment: Did you use `up` or `run` to start the container?

Comment: i used run to start it